# Export functions from another file clisp

Tags: lisp, clisp

I am using the programming language clisp.
I have some functions X,Y,Z in a .lisp file, lets say A.Now I am writing a different program in .lisp file B and I need to make use of the X,Y,Z.

How do i import functions in Clisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLISP` is not really a programming language. It is an implementation of the programming language *Common Lisp* with many extensions.

You can load files with the function [LOAD](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm).

Answer (score 2):

clisp implements common lisp functions so:

```
(load 'myfile)
```